# Prototype find class and replace text

Tags: javascript, replace, prototypejs

I am using the prototype framework [requirement by platform] and I am trying to find a ID and replace some text in the ID so that it disappears.

The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="top">
<a href="/login">login</a> | <a href="/register">register</a>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't want the " | " to appear in the ID "top". So I guess it's sort of "find element " | " in ID top and remove"

```
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
try { 
if ($$('#top')!=null) {

var topmenu = document.getElementById('top');
var value = topmenu.value;
// define an array of replacements
var replacements = [
    { from: '|', to: ' ' }
];
for (var i = 0, replacement; i < replacements.length, replacement = replacements[i]; i++) {
    // replace
    value = value.replace(replacement.from, replacement.to);
}
// replace the old text with the new
topmenu.value = value;    
} } 
catch(ex) {
}
});
```

Tried with this above but doesn't work. Can anyone assist ?

Thanks

Comment: Your use of the word "class" is weird.  The word "top" is the *id* of the div surrounding your two anchor tags; none of those elements have a "class" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use CSS to hide the pipe? Just change the `color` to match the `background-color` so that it is invisible.

```
#top {color: #fff } /* substitute with the right background color if different */
#top a {color: #000 } /* or whatever it has to be */
```

**EDIT:** The right property you should be replacing is `innerHTML`, not `value`.

```
var value = topmenu.innerHTML;
// define an array of replacements
var replacements = [
    { from: '|', to: ' ' }
];
for (var i = 0, replacement; i < replacements.length, replacement = replacements[i]; i++) {
    // replace
    value = value.replace(replacement.from, replacement.to);
}
// replace the old text with the new
topmenu.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: hi - not sure what you mean? i just want to hide the " | " not the entire <a>. ?

Comment: Yes, that is why you override the color of `#top a` to whatever you want it to be so that the anchors are visible while the "|" isn't

Comment: hi - yeah thanks :) but the problem is also that sometimes there is plain text in the header that I want to keep

Comment: haha LEGEND! :))) works great. thank you so much - was really pulling my hair out and couldnt see the obvious )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need quotes around the |. Otherwise it looks okay. Probably don't need the conditional either since you're in a try catch but maybe that's just too loosy goosy.

Comment: hey thanks - i am actually trying to keep the <a> 's and just "remove " the " | "